# Testcafe: I updated testcafe to 0.23.2 and the tests tripled the execution time

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

Browser: All

Testcafe: v0.23.0

node.js: v8.12.0

OS: macOS, Windows 10

**Since the update (0.21.0 -> 0.23.2), the execution time of the tests tripled. 
Have any of you experienced this since the update?**

Test Scenario: I want to launch a general regression test suite

Current Behaviour: - Some of the tests fail because of timeout-related issues
- Each action takes ~ 1 second more, the whole suite takes ~ 35 minutes

Expected Behaviour: - 100% tests passed in ~ 10 minutes

Comment: I suggest to file an issue https://github.com/devexpress/testcafe/issues

Comment: Yes..I will. I wanted to ask here before.

Answer (score 1):

We have not experienced these kinds of performance issues. Moreover, we haven't noticed any performance slowdown in our [tests](https://travis-ci.org/DevExpress/testcafe). Thus I recommend you create a bug report in our github repository. Please use the [special template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) for creating a bug. I kindly ask you to fill all fields and provide as many details as possible. If you use any CI system, specify this in the ticket as well. It could happen that the cause of the issue is in CI unstable behavior.

You could also check the `0.23.3-alpha.1` version. It contains fixes which can affect the performance (eg https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3070).